# How to add dragstart event in bootstrap vue tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I added @dragstart event on b-tab of bootstrap-vue.
But I cannot see it in "Event Listners" in inspect.

```
b-tab(
    v-for="value, index in lists",
    :key="value.table_id",
    lazy,
    :active='value.active',
    :draggable="true",
    @dragstart="drag($event)",
    :id="value.table_name",
)
```

[Event Listeners Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve25j.png)

Comment: That places the event/attribute on the tab content holder, not the tab "button".  Use the tab `title` scoped slot and wrap the title in a `<div>` or `<span>` that has the event handler and attribute.